# Access variable property by name as string in n-dimensional object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a multi-dimensional object `data`, and I want to fetch a given branch of it via a string. Example:

```
data = {
    title: 'Hi',
    topics: {
        title: 'Yey',
        general: {       
            topics: {
            description: 'Desc'
        }
    }
}
```

The dimensions of the object are variable. What I want is to be able to import the whole object, and then dynamically pick the branch I want, like so:

```
import data from './dataFile'

let branchString = 'data.topics.general'
let myBranch = data + branchString // this obviously doesn't work
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fun side fact: i flagged another question as the same duplicate like 5 minutes ago

Comment: The duplicate answer is not satisfying. A fast answer would be : let myBranch=   eval(branchString.replace(/\./gm,'"]["').replace(/\"]\[/,'[')+'"]');